# I cannot log in to some sites after I've reinstalled Windows

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, passwords, authentication

How do you think, what can be the problem: I'm 100% sure that I input correct login and password but I cannot to pass authentication on some sites (not all).

I have a sony vaio laptop and I've just reinstalled Windows (now I have Windows 7).

Comment: That really sounds like you've forgotten which password you've used for those websites you can't log into. I can't fathom why a fresh install of an operating system would cause that. Is it consistently the same sites you cannot log into?

Comment: @JBirch: I know myself that it looks like some magic. But one of these sites I use almost every day and I always input password manually. I just cannot mistype it or forgot it.

Comment: @JBirch: anyway, tomorrow I'll fix that (I'll go to admins) but I just don't understand..

Comment: @Roman well, if you're sure, then there's little else I can do but take you at your word. You might need to provide some additional information, however. What operating system were you running before? What browser were you running before versus now? Can you successfully log on from a different machine? Can you successfully log on with a different browser?

Comment: @JBirch: you know, I did log in.. after reloading.

Comment: @JBirch: and what was your idea? I had Vista, now I have Windows 7. I used Chrome, now I tried in both Chrome and IE.

Comment: @Roman: No idea as of yet - just general problem solving. Try and narrow down the differences between what works and what doesn't and take it from there. Happy you figured it out, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check your language settings. It is possible that your newly installed Windows uses a different keyboard layout than the previous installation.

This can occur if, for example, your old installation was German and you forgot to specify German keyboard layout in the new installation. Normally you would notice something like that quickly, but if it's not US/German but perhaps US/UK then the difference can be small - but just might affect the placement of characters you only use in passwords!